# SerialPort.Close() and Event Handlers

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a WPF program in which I am reading in quite a lot of data from a Serial Port, and at the moment I am looping through with a for loop reading in data a packet at a time and writing it to a file. I want to make this an event handled operation, so that the UI can continue to be updated whilst this is ongoing.

I thought it would be best to use the `SerialPort.DataReceived` event for this purpose, however I would need to be able to remove this handler from my `SerialPort` object on completion of the task. Is this done when I call `Close()`? Or would I need to remove the handler by some other means?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the handler? Close doesn't remove the handler but it won't be called anymore.

Comment: I did look on the MSDN libraries... but it doesn't mention this.

Comment: I need to remove the handler because there are other times when I am using the port when I don't want to deal with data in an event-driven way.

Comment: So putting mySerialPort.DataReceived -= MyHandler; in your Close() does not work?

Comment: You should be able to remove a handler at any time the same way that you add it, except you use -= instead of +=.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just write a warper for the SerialPort then. And have the wrapper keep track of the handlers and remove them when closing. (So you don't have to implement this logic in all instances of use.) using the -= method.

Each instance would need there own event to store the calls. (not to fire them)

For example:

```
    private event EventHandler myHandle;
    public event EventHandler myExposedHandle
    {
        add
        {
            myHandle += value;
            serialPort.DataReceived += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            myHandle -= value;
            serialPort.DataReceived -= value;
        }
    }
    public void removeFunction()
    {
        myHandle = null;
        serialPort.DataReceived -= myHandle;
    }
```

Comment: If I set the event handler to a += new EventHandler(foo); How do I then reference that handler when I want to do -=?

Comment: I edited to add an example of doing that. You could store them in another unused event and subtract the unused event from the event you are using.

Comment: Edited it again for a more elegant approach for a warper.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reusing the same SerialPort object, just set the event to null to remove your handler. As long as there aren't stacked handlers this should work fine; otherwise, it gets a little more complicated.

Comment: Don't set to null.  Use -= as Stu and 500 mentioned in the original comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the handler, but instead, test for when you need it in the handler logic.